# CKEditor 4: add dynamic select element in plugin dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, ckeditor

I'm trying to populate a select element with data from an Ajax query. I am receiving the data:

> ['And here's a comment on this Bookmark. ..., 250'], ['Wow,
>   another comment. ..., 251'], ['Okay, it's just another comment.
>   ..., 252']

... but I cannot populate the actual select element with the data. So far, I have:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'commentDialog', function( editor ) {

    function get_bookmark_comments_as_object () {
        var objBookmark = new Object({
            items: []
        });
        objBookmark.id = 7193;
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "comments/jq_get_bookmark_comments_as_object/" + objBookmark.id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (element) {
                for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                    objBookmark.items.push("['" + element[i].comment_snippet + ", " + element[i].bookmark_comment_id + "']");
                }
                String.prototype.unquoted = function () { return this.replace (/(^")|("$)/g, '') }
                var string = objBookmark.items.join(', ');
                console.log(string);
                return string.unquoted();
            },
            error: function () {

            }
        });
    }

...
```

... and:

```
return {
    // Basic properties of the dialog window: title, minimum size.
    title: 'Comment Properties',
    minWidth: 400,
    minHeight: 200,
    // Dialog window contents definition.
    contents: [
        {
            // Definition of the Basic Settings dialog tab (page).
            id: 'tab-basic',
            label: 'Basic Settings',
            // The tab contents.
            elements: [
                {
                    // Text input field for the abbreviation text.
                    type: 'select',
                    id: 'comment',
                    label: 'Select a Comment',
                    items: [['Select a Comment', 0]].concat( get_bookmark_comments_as_object() ),
                    setup: function( element ) {
                        this.setValue( element.getText() );
                    },
                    commit: function( element ) {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

As you can see from the `get_bookmark_comments_as_object()` function, I'm returning a string in the exact format.

Any attempt to return a plain array or string makes the select element behave weird (the double quotes surrounding a string, for example, causes CKEditor to split the entire string into character parts). Yet, when I copy and paste from the `console.log()` results, it works.

I've tried a multitude of variations for `items: ...` with no usable results.

Ive tried placing the jQuery / Ajax code in `setup: ...` and `commit: ...` with no usable results.

I've also tried the [fix from a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633504/ckeditor-populate-dialog-select-with-ajax), but that doesn't do anything either.

I've gone as far as I'm able, and what remains is a mystery to me.

**Update**

After some bashing around, I've discovered that:

```
var items = [['And here&#39;s a comment on this Bookmark. ...', '250'], ['Wow, another comment. ...', '251'], ['Okay, it&#39;s just another comment. ...', '252']];
```

... works, whereas:

```
var items = get_bookmark_comments_as_object();
```

... doesn't, even though the strings are identical.

So, for whatever reason, CKEditor (or, I assume, JavaScript) is choking on I know not what.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in that situation on a CKEDITOR widget dialog.

```
id: 'modelStudentCaseVariable',
type: 'select',
label: 'Student Case',
items: [
    [ editor.lang.common.notSet, '' ]
],

onLoad: function (widget) {
    var selectList = this;
    var url = $("#studentCaseVarsUrl").val();
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            selectList.add(key, val);
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: This is not working for me, i got the following error `selectList.add is not a function` because 'this' is the dialog it cannot work or I'm missing something in your answer...

Comment: It's been a while since I've been into the specifics of CKEDITOR.  Sorry, I'm not sure for your case.  =/

Answer (score 0):

To do this reliably, I found that you have to do the AJAX request in the 'onLoad' function of the widget. From there, you can populate the widget using its "add" function. A gotcha is that you need to assign the widget to a variable (using 'this') outside of your AJAX callback function.

```
{
    type: 'select',
    id: 'myselect',
    label: 'The select will be empty until it is populated',
    items: [ ],
    onLoad: function(api) {
        widget = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'path/to/your/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    widget.add(data[i]['label'], data[i]['value']);
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log('ajax error ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
            },
        });
    },
},
```